# Where can I find a "bulb ramping" intervalometer which will work with a Canon T3i?

Tags: equipment-recommendation, timelapse, intervalometer, bulb-ramping

I am looking to do time-lapses during sunset and sunrise.  I have a EOS 600d/T3i.  My current intervalometer is pretty cheap and will not work for this.  I believe I need a "Bulb Ramping" intervalometer.  Does anyone know of a good one and where I might be able to buy it?  Thank you!

I have read a little bit on the "[Little Bramper](http://www.thewhippersnapper.com/LittleBramper/Site/Home.html)", but it says it is "unknown"  as far as working for the T3i.

Answer (score 4):

Promote Systems has what you need. Buy [Promote Remote Control](http://www.promotesystems.com/products/Promote-Control.html) with [bulb ramping kit](http://www.promotesystems.com/products/Promote-Control-Bulb-Ramping-and-Bulb-HDR-Assistant-Kit.html). It is the best and most powerful solution on the market.

*What makes it "best and most powerful"?*

It's got more features than a swiss knife!

1. Single Shot mode
2. Stack focusing (dream feature for macro photographers)
3. High Dynamic Range (up to 9 EV stops, much higher than any internal bracketing of any camera on the market)
4. Bulb Ramping (if you're into time-lapse photography, this feature alone is worth the money. It's a Godsend)
5. Manual Shutter Hold (for bulb shooting)
6. Bulb HDR Ramping (this feature is cutting edge)
7. Time-lapse
8. Time-lapse HDR (makes a really tedious task super easy and intuitive)
9. Hyperfocal calculator

Device is also weather sealed and it's got a large backlit LCD. Promote Remote controls the camera via shutter release cable + USB cable and in case of Bulb Ramping, it is connected to the camera via shutter-cable + PC Sync cable.
P.R. has a complete control over your camera, its auto-focusing mechanism, mirror-locking, etc.

I own pretty much ALL remotes out there and have tested them extensively over the past 2 years. 
Promote Remote is a super-robust, professional workhorse for a serious photographer and in terms of features and performance, it is in a league of its own. Promote System's tech support is top notch and firmware updates keep adding the new and exciting functionality to the already impressive list of features.
In short, there's no other device on the market that can even remotely compare to Promote Remote.

Comment: Wow, thats a hell of a remote!

Answer (score 2):

[Magic Lantern](http://magiclantern.wikia.com/wiki/Unified) for Canon T3i has support for Bulb Ramping and Intervalometer.  Personally I do use Magic Lantern on my 60D and had no problems with it but I have not tried those features yet.
Magic Lantern is a **free** software that sits on top of your Canon firmware.  You can get more information about it on their [website](http://magiclantern.wikia.com/wiki/Unified).

Answer (score 1):

It looks like [the reason Nikon cameras can't do bulb ramping](http://www.elysia.nl/content/bulb-ramping-nikon-dslr-technical-story) is because their bulb mode only works in discrete steps, and doesn't allow precise control. While the [Little Bramper site](http://www.thewhippersnapper.com/LittleBramper/Site/Home.html) says that newer Canon Rebel models aren't tested, I don't see any reason to believe that they *wouldn't* work. There's no sign that Canon has changed how they do things (and I think there would be outcry if they had).

The Arduino-based [TriggerTrap](http://triggertrap.com/) doesn't have this functionality, although they are apparently looking at adding it in an update. I mention it, though, because they have [an extensive list of supported models](http://triggertrap.com/supported-cameras/) and the Rebel T3i is on the list with all the rest with no special note.

So, anyway, I think you will be safe with the Little Bramper. There's apparently a [30-day no-questions return policy](http://www.thewhippersnapper.com/LittleBramper/Site/How_To_Order.html), so if it doesn't work you'll only be out the (note: rather high) cost of shipping. I think it's a decent gamble.

For what it's worth, apparently [Pentax cameras work with this, too](http://www.pentaxforums.com/forums/photographic-technique/145694-new-type-intervalometer.html).

Answer (score 1):

Photix has a new intervalometer with features that seem equivalent to the Promote for about 1/3 of the cost. I just picked one up and I'm starting to experiment with it, and it looks like it'll get the job done for me without spending as much; it's also got cables so it'll work with both the 7d and t3i with the same unit (unlike Canon's units), which is very convenient for me...

with my early looks at the Aion, it seems to have good build quality and other than an instruction manual that is pretty useless, the hardware seems to be a good value.

http://www.phottix.com/en/wireless-remotes/phottix-aion-wireless-timer-and-shutter-release.html

Answer (score 0):

The best solution to your problem can be solved using the Magic Lantern firmware addon for the many different Canon versions including Canon 500/550 and 600D that was mentioned previously and a free lightroom extension called LRTimelapse

- [Magiclantern.wikia.com](http://Magiclantern.wikia.com)
- http://lrtimelapse.com/

Magic Lantern is my first choice, even over most hardware intervalometers you can purchase. I have been using it for quite a while for Timelapses and I am satisfied with it.

You can read more [here](http://magiclantern.wikia.com/wiki/Unified/UserGuide#intervalometer) about the Intervalometer of the Magic lantern addon

The great thing with LR Timelapse is that you can simulate bulbramping if you don't want to use the bulb ramping from the Magic Lantern when using it to create your timelapse videos.

Answer (score 0):

I think [Timelapse+](https://www.timelapseplus.com/) is the best option out there nowadays... it's kind of not so cheap at $199, but I think will do fine.

Comment: How much is not so cheap? It would help to have that info direct here in the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can shoot in Aperture Priority mode and have your sequence de-flickered with [TLDF](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/tldf-timelapse-deflicker/id1150061142?mt=12#). You can see the demo on [YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=s69dnocBwxY).