# How can I shoot sunrise/sunset timelapses with a smooth sky gradient transition?

Tags: timelapse

I want to shoot a timelapse sequence of a sunrise using my Canon 200D. It does support a timelapse video mode, but the settings are quite limited - I can either set everything manually, set auto-exposure for the first shot only or set auto-exposure for all shots. If I try shooting in the first two exposure modes I get the obvious problem of the scene getting too bright as the sun comes out in the sky. If I set the camera to auto-exposure on every shot I get uneven lighting as the exposure meter doesn't guarantee a smooth gradient.

I've read online that the solution to this issue is to use a **bulb intervalometer**, which essentially let's you fine tune how quickly the exposure changes between shots. However devices that support this are quite costly (300$+) and I'd rather not invest in them right now. Is it possible to achieve the same effect by connecting a phone or a laptop to the camera and using a piece of third-party software?

[Here's an example of what I'm trying to achieve](https://youtu.be/cIOUoSlkZ9A)

Comment: You might have better luck finding software that takes your sequence of auto-exposure images and adjusts the exposure in each one to create a smooth transition.

Comment: Never tried doing this before, but would a graduated ND placed at the horizon line solve for allowing a more consistent exposure from foreground to sky as the sun comes up?

Comment: @Caleb I've thought of that too but couldn't find it after a quick search.

Comment: @Corey a graduated filter solves a different problem. I need to get the sky to evenly transition in color between shots, avoiding any visible 'jumps'

Comment: @NikitaSokolsky - gotcha - would love to learn more. Do you have a link to something you're trying to replicate?

Comment: @Corey post updated.

Comment: Nearly a duplicate: [Where can I find a “bulb ramping” intervalometer which will work with a Canon T3i?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/18003/4262)

Comment: @Caleb I did see that post but Magic Lantern doesn't work for my camera and I don't want to buy an extra device

Comment: @NikitaSokolsky It looks like your 200D lacks a connection for a wired remote; if that's true, the intervalometers on the market won't work with your body anyway.

Comment: @NikitaSokolsky - Still researching it - but I'll have to give it a shot to be sure - but it seems that shooting auto through the sun cresting the horizon would work, then using a grad ND and auto shooting to keep sky and foreground in alignment through the rest of sun-up would get all the shots exposed correctly - and other fine-tuning could be done in post no?

Answer (score 1):

One option is:

- Get a manual lens, probably a cinema lens, or one that does not "snap" too easily.
- Make your calculations on the aperture range.
- Make calculations on how are the increments you need to make.
- Change the aperture manually.
- Shoot in raw so you can make micro adjustments in post.

Answer (score 0):

Buy a simple intervalometer from Amazon. Expose each frame for half the time of the interval between frames to get smooth results.

Comment: You misunderstand the question. OP isn't asking about smooth video _motion_. He's asking about smooth _exposure_ transition because the large change in light levels during a sunrise or sunset.