# Change exposure settings while shooting with intervalometer

Tags: canon, timelapse, exposure-correction

I own a Canon 77D camera with built-in intervalometer. I can set the interval in seconds between shots and set it to either shoot indefinitely or a fixed amount of shots. When I shoot the sunrise or sunset (a.k.a. The Holy Grail) timelapse I need to adjust exposure (mainly shutter speed) in order to compensate for dramatically changing brightness of the scene. Problem is that in order to do that I need to turn the camera off to abort the indefinite interval shooting, then turn it on, adjust the shutter speed and turn the interval shooting again. This takes time and causes an uneven interval between shots. Is there a way to adjust exposure settings without interrupting the interval setup? E.g. tell the camera to shoot the next frame with a different shutter speed than the previous one.

If this cannot be done with the built-in intervalometer then can it be achieved with some external one?

Or is there another trick to work around it? P.S. I'm using LRTimelapse and Adobe Lightroom for post-processing.

Comment: Related: [What is bulb ramping?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/19007/15871) and [Where can I find a “bulb ramping” intervalometer which will work with a Canon T3i?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/18003/15871)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not a very big problem when there is a little bit bigger interval in between the images as long as you keep it short because it is not that easy to see in the video from the lighting perspective. Subjectwise its something different. To do it this easy it is easier to use a external intervalometer because you don't have to go in menus to stop and start it.

But have you tried to change it just in between the intervals? My Nikon D7200 let me do this in between the shots if I have everything in manual mode and also the lighting compensation in the build in intervalometer disabled without stopping the interval. To get the best looking footage on a holy grail timelapse it is the easiest to change it often but only in small steps. So you will just turn the time wheel for one step every couple of images.

If you need more resources or tips to this topic I would reccomend you take a look at the work of Matthew Vandeputte. He has some great [youtube video tutorials](https://youtu.be/xm5KwHjI0bY) and also a very good [description on his website](https://www.matjoez.com/2018/07/30/complete-guide-to-shooting-and-editing-holy-grail-timelapses/) where he describes exactly your problem in the steps but he only works with external intervalometers.

Comment: Wow I am an idiot. I can indeed change shutter speed with the wheel beside the shutter button and also ISO with the dedicated iso button. All that in between shots. Thanks for opening my eyes

Comment: However I noticed that in order for the image preview to appear after each shot (with crucial histogram information) I need to shoot with interval of 7s or more. You probably don't know how to make it work with shorter intervals in a Canon camera right?

Comment: no need to get harsh here. some cameras are limiting you that they are not letting you change these things without stopping the internal timer. The external intervalometer just extracts this and the camera does not know that it is triggered by an intervalometer so this cannot happen

Comment: I personally are not really adapting this by just the histogram i change it when i see that it is getting lower on the ev scale on the small screen on the top of my camera and then i either stop it and reset it correctly or i just adapt it by feel.

Comment: Ev scale is a good hint indeed. On the other hand 7 seconds is not that bad for a timelapse. Anyway thanks again for your help!

Comment: no i cannot say to you how to exactly solve this problem because i am a Nikon shooter but i am not working with the image preview to save a little bit of batterie. maybe the linked blogpost in my answer could help you and give you more clearence because matthew is a canon shooter

Comment: 7 seconds can be good or also bad its always depending on the subject you are shooting but if it is a landscape or a cityscape and the most moving things are clouds it can be very good

Comment: most of my timelapses have a interval of 8 to 12 seconds